# Linux makefile debug library

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I want to write a makefile for a static library. And I need a version of that library with debug information to do some debugging..

This is what I have:

```
CC=g++
SRCDIR=../../src

SRCCORE = $(SRCDIR)/core/lodepng.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyBasicFileProvider.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyBezierCurve.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyBone.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCamera.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyClient.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyColor.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyConfig.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCore.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCoreFileProvider.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCoreInput.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCoreServices.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyCubemap.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyData.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyEntity.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyEvent.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyEventDispatcher.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyEventHandler.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyFont.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyFontGlyphSheet.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyFontManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyGPUDrawBuffer.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyImage.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyInputEvent.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyLabel.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyLogger.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyMaterial.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyMaterialManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyMatrix4.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyMesh.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyObject.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyOpenGLGraphicsInterface.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyPAAudioInterface.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyParticleEmitter.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyPeer.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyPerlin.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyPhysFSFileProvider.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyQuaternion.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyQuaternionCurve.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyRay.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyRectangle.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyRenderDataArray.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyRenderer.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyResource.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyResourceManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyScene.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneEntityInstance.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneImage.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneLabel.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneLight.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneLine.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneMesh.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyScenePrimitive.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneRenderTexture.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneSound.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySceneSprite.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyServer.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyShader.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySkeleton.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySocket.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySound.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySoundManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyString.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyTexture.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyThreaded.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyTimer.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyTimerManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyTween.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyTweenManager.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyVector2.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyVector3.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolyVector4.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/rgbe.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/tinystr.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/tinyxml.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/tinyxmlerror.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/tinyxmlparser.cpp $(SRCDIR)/core/PolySDLCore.cpp

OBJCORE=$(SRCCORE:.cpp=.o)

SRCTEMPLATE=$(SRCDIR)/view/linux/PolycodeView.cpp TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplateApp.cpp TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplate.cpp
OBJTEMPLATE=$(SRCTEMPLATE:.cpp=.o)

CFLAGS=-I../../include -g -DDEBUG

LIBDIR=../../lib/linux

LDFLAGS=-L$(LIBDIR) -lPolycore -lfreetype -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lphysfs -lz -lX11 -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lSDL -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL
LDFLAGS_DEBUG=-L$(LIBDIR) -lPolycored -lfreetype -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lphysfs -lz -lX11 -lrt -ldl -lpthread -lSDL -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL

default: setup core

setup:
    @mkdir -p $(LIBDIR)

.cpp.o:
    @echo "Building "$<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

core: $(OBJCORE)
    @echo "Linking $(LIBDIR)/libPolycore.a"
    @ar rcs $(LIBDIR)/libPolycore.a $(OBJCORE)

debug: $(OBJCORE)
    @echo "Linking $(LIBDIR)/libPolycored.a"
    @ar rcs $(LIBDIR)/libPolycored.a $(OBJCORE)

template: $(OBJTEMPLATE)
    @echo "Linking TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplate"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJTEMPLATE) -o TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplate

templateDebug: $(OBJTEMPLATE)
    @echo "Linking TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplate"
    @$(CC) -DDEBUG -g $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_DEBUG) $(OBJTEMPLATE) -o TemplateApp/PolycodeTemplate

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJCORE) $(LIBDIR)/libPolycore.a $(LIBDIR)/libPolycored.a
```

To make clear what I need:
I want to be able to debug the code of the files listed in SRCCORE in KDevelop (using GDB) when running the PolycodeTemplate.

I'm at the end of my knowledge about makefiles :$
Thanks for all help!

Comment: Your makefile should be good to go. But I will change `CC` to `CXX` and `CFLAGS` to `CXXFLAGS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to build a separate version of each translation unit, with the debugging flags turned on, namely -g.

Normally, each `.cpp` translation unit gets compiled into a `.o`, and you understand the rule for doing so. Pick an extension for the debug version, let's use ".do":

```
DEBUGFLAGS= -g

.cpp.do:
    @echo "Building "$<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now, `foo.cpp` is going to get compiled into `foo.do` using the `-g` flag. So, this comes down to:

a) Assembling your regular library the way you're doing now.

b) Assembling your debug library from `.do` files, instead of `.lo` files.

I see that your Makefile already defines:

```
OBJCORE=$(SRCCORE:.cpp=.o)

# ...

    @ar rcs $(LIBDIR)/libPolycore.a $(OBJCORE)
```

Ok, so now, let's add this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .do

DOBJCORE=$(SRCCORE:.cpp=.do)
```

And your homework assignment is going to be to figure out what you need to do with your "debug" target, to make use of it.

P.S. If you later intend to turn on optimizations, do not add `-O2`, or some such, to `CFLAGS`. Define a separate `OPTFLAGS` macro, and add it to your `.cpp.o` target only, so that the debug version of the library is still not optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer so far. It sounds like it should work if I change those things you've told me to change.. but it says: `make: *** No rule to make target '../../src/core/lodepng.do', needed by 'debug'.  Stop.`
See my new makefile [here](http://pastebin.com/DF1QerUQ)

Comment: @fodinabor - oh, I think you need to set .SUFFIXES=.do also, edited my answer.

Comment: thank you! that fixes that issue - but there is now another issue which makes me think whether the linking works: I get tons of `undefined reference to` issues - these references now should all be found in libPolycored.a - g++ seems to find it as it does not say it did not find it... so could it be that the archive is not correctly created? Or not correctly linked? (did not change anything but the SUFFIXES thing from my last status)

Comment: @fodinabor this is something you'll just have to figure out yourself. You can use the "ar" command to examine and verify the contents of the created library.